# if i want to allow user to do calculation again, what should i do here?

Tags: python

#the required actions:

```
def multiplication(num1, num2):
    return num1*num2
def submisstion(num1, num2):
    return num1+num2
def subtract(num1, num2):
    return num1-num2
def div(num1, num2):
    return num1/num2
def power(num1, num2):
    return num1**num2
```

#taking user inputs

```
num1 = float(input("num1"))
calculation = input()
num2 = float(input("num2"))
```

#here i want to run the calculation upon user inputs

```
if calculation == "*":
    print(multiplication((num1), (num2)))
elif calculation == "+":
    print(submisstion((num1), (num2)))
elif calculation == "-":
    print(subtract(num1), (num2))
elif calculation == "/":
    print(div((num1), (num2)))
elif calculation == "^":
    print(power((num1), (num2)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need an infinite loop to give the user the chance to input several calculations, in addition to a certain keyword to close the program:

```
while True:
    num1 = float(input("num1: "))
    calculation = input()
    num2 = float(input("num2: "))
    #here i want to run the calculation upon user inputs
    
    if calculation == "*":
        print(multiplication((num1), (num2)))
    elif calculation == "+":
        print(submisstion((num1), (num2)))
    elif calculation == "-":
        print(subtract(num1), (num2))
    elif calculation == "/":
        print(div((num1), (num2)))
    elif calculation == "^":
        print(power((num1), (num2)))
    elif calculation == "End program":
        break
```